# Adding Font's to resources - C#

Tags: c#

I have a program with a custom font in it, but when my friend downloaded the program, the font didn't show up because he didn't install it.
Is there any way for a font to automaticly install? 
Or atleast show up for every body.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always include a manual reference to the font, and store it locally with the program.

Comment: How do i do that? (sorry i'm still a big noob when it come's to these things :s)

Comment: Create an installer package and deploy the font along with your program, or you can keep the font with your exe and use a [`PrivateFontCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always include the font with the program, and check if the font is installed on launch

```
string fontName = "Times New Roman";
using(Font tester = new Font(fontName, 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel) {
    // If font doesn't exist
    if(!tester.Name == fontName) {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($fontInstallerPath);
    }
}
```

And that's it. Just put this in your Main function, and when the user starts the application it will prompt them to install the font if they don't already have it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work very well.. i'm getting alot errors

Comment: 131 errors, but i think ill just use an animated gif for the font, thanks got you help though